# Replies, comments and changes lack userids

Tags: google-drive-api

At present, there are no handles to uniquely identify userids in changes, comments or replies.
This makes it really hard to cache some of this data under userid.

Is there a plan to add userids beyond just the usernames ?

Answer (score 1):

The permissionId of the user is currently presented in the changes feeds:

```
"lastModifyingUser": {
"kind": "drive#user",
"displayName": "Andrew Smith",
 "picture": {
  "url": ...
 },
 "permissionId": "05830388977156113623"
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. Is the permissionId a) unique per user b) immutable c) available in contexts where I don't have a drive service ?

Basically what I want to know is that if I want to key things in my application that are based off a userid.
Secondly, once a user is logged in, but hasn't made any Drive API calls, I would like to be able to retrieve this information. Is there a way to go from a login credential to a permissionId?