# Is permissionId unique for a user?

Tags: google-drive-api

Follow up to:
[Replies, comments and changes lack userids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999870/replies-comments-and-changes-lack-userids)

i.e. is there a one to one mapping permissionId a 1-1 mapping between a permission and a user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

From what I've been told by Google Support yes. This is the identifier they are using internally to associate each account and their permissions to a document.